# How can I ignore empty groups?

Tags: python, regex

Pretty straightforward regex, I am trying to extract IP from logs. But group(1) is empty, which is given. Is there a better way to approach this problem?

```
sourceip_regex_extract = re.compile(r"{}".format(sourceip_syslog_regex))
sourceip_extract = sourceip_regex_extract.search(message) 
sourceip_txt = sourceip_extract.group(1)
```

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/jmtQci/1

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/jmtQci/2, `\b(?:from |inside:)(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})`

Comment: Can you break this down? plus regex101 says "Your regular expression does not match the subject string."

Comment: I added `\b`, remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when you search for a match with a regex, make sure you actually get a match and only then access the first group value.

Next, `r"{}".format(sourceip_syslog_regex)` makes no sense, it is the same as `sourceip_syslog_regex`.

To fix the current issue, you can use a `(?:from |inside:)` alternation to match either `from`  or `inside:`

```py
sourceip_syslog_regex = r'(?:from |inside:)(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})'
sourceip_regex_extract = re.compile(sourceip_syslog_regex)
sourceip_extract = sourceip_regex_extract.search(message) 
if sourceip_extract:
    sourceip_txt = sourceip_extract.group(1)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jmtQci/3)

Note you can shorten the IP address matching pattern a bit and use `(?:from |inside:)(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})`.

*Details*:

- `(?:from |inside:)` - either `from`  or `inside:`
- `(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})` - Group 1: one to three digits and then three occurrences of a `.` and one to three digits.

Comment: Ah! Well actually that was the variable. But yes you are right thanks man!